# How Do I Get The Remote Port of TCP/UDP Socket Pair of Some Other Process

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, process

On Linux, suppose we have the PID of some process which is running on the machine. Is it possible to get all the remote ports of all socket pairs this process has? How?

We are able to get the ports which are owned by this process by parsing the outputs of executing `netstat -anp | grep PID`, I can do it by getting the IP address of this machine via `getifaddrs()`  then drag the part after xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:. But I am not able to know the ip addresses of the other ends which is communicating with target process.

Comment: Doesn't netstat show the remote address of each connected socket automatically? UDP sockets that are not bound to a remote address would obviously have no remote side but the rest would.

Comment: Netstat -n provides the foreign addresses as well as their port number.

Answer (score 1):

**TCP**
Use `netstat -n` to show remote addresses and ports.

**UDP**
Note that the above doesn't apply to UDP because UDP doesn't have the concept of "connections", hence cannot have a remote address and port. Instead, each UDP message has a source address and port and is handled by a single socket in the destination process. I'm sure there are other ways, but personally I used wireshark to catch UDP packets. As you may have realized, you won't know the remote address until you actually receive a message.